# getting data from a pointcloud2 coming from Kinect

Tags: pcl, pointcloud, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on getting depth data from Kinect. as i understand, the point cloud topic from Kinect (/camera/depth/points2) directly provides depth data in meters in the form of a pointcloud2 (please correct me if I am wrong!)

however, after browsing through pointcloud2 documentation, I did not find any method to, say, access the value of a specific point in the point cloud. then I read somewhere that pointcloud2 is abstracted in such a way that data cannot be accessed directly from it. (is that true?)

could anyone help me out with getting data from the pointcloud2 topic that I am subscribing to?
thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10363/getting-data-from-a-pointcloud2-coming-from-kinect/) by [surfexceltide](https://answers.ros.org/users/687/surfexceltide/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-06-22**:
Try to search through the history of questions. This answer was already asked a few times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably will want to use the Point Cloud Library (http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl) to access and manipulate cloud data. There are several tutorials available.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4